# can not load audio file in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am trying to load an audio file on button click via the following code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Audio Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateSource(){
            var audio = document.getElementById('wavSource');
            audio.src = 'A REMOTE URL FOR WAV AUDIO';
            var a = document.getElementById('audio');
            a.load();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="audio" controls="controls">
        <source id="wavSource" src="" type="audio/wav"></source>
        Your browser does not support the audio format.
    </audio>
    <button onclick="updateSource();">Item1</button>
</body>
```

The WAV audio file resides on a diffrent web server. The above code run perfectly on firefox but does not work in Google Chrome. When I try to play the audio from console, it returns a pending promise. Can anyone please explain this behavior?

Comment: could it be, that this is because of the recent change in chrome, that deactivates autoplay?

Comment: I dont know. I am not autoplaying it anyway. The audio file specified in the `src` resides in a specific path on a remote machine.